# Animate viewForOverlay MKCircleView

Tags: iphone, delegates, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I want to animate the circle that I'm adding as an MKOverLay. I want it to drop from the top of the screen. How do I animate through the delegate method? Or is it in the addition of the overlay? Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

I have this in the mapView Delegate Method

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{

    if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]]) {
        // Create the view for the radius overlay.
        MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];

        return circleView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

And I add overLays like so:

```
        MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:userCoord radius:200];
        [mainMapView addOverlay:circle];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to have a scale up + fade in animation, you might do this:

```
@interface MyMapOverlayView : UIView<CAAction>
@end

@implementation MyMapOverlayView

- (id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)event
{
    if ( [ event isEqualToString:@"onOrderIn" ] )
    {
        return self ;
    }

    return [ super actionForLayer:layer forKey:event ] ;
}

- (void)runActionForKey:(NSString *)event object:(id)anObject arguments:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    if ( [ event isEqualToString:@"onOrderIn" ] )
    {
        {
            CABasicAnimation * anim = [ CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform" ] ;
            anim.fromValue = [ NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale( 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f ) ] ;
            [ self.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil ] ;
        }

        {
            CABasicAnimation * anim = [ CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity" ] ;
            anim.fromValue = @0.0f ;
            [ self.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil ] ;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

n.b.: I took a guess at how you might add these animations *at the time your overlay is added to the map view*, but I haven't tested it. You will need to experiment. You might be able to just set them when the view is created.

**update**: I tested it, it seems to work.

Comment: I actually want to add on this method where I draw the circle overlay. Should I add your code above to my MyCustomCircle class?            MKCircle *circle2 = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:userCoord radius:[self convertToMetersFromDegrees:radius]];
            MyCustomCircle *myCircleView = [[MyCustomCircle alloc] initWithCircle:circle2];
            [mainMapView addOverlay:myCircleView.circle];

Comment: I'd say if you are animating myCircleView, add this code to MyCustomCircle--it will animate when it's added to a parent view

Answer (score 1):

Here's some untested code. If it does work, you may have to alter the animation.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddOverlayViews:(NSArray *)overlayViews
{
    for (MKOverlayView *view in overlayViews) {

        CGRect endFrame = view.frame;
        view.frame = CGRectMake(endFrame.origin.x, endFrame.origin.y-500, 0, 0);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            view.frame = endFrame;
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is firing, and breakpoints are hitting the for and the statement inside the for loop, but there's no animation. if I change the -500 to -50000 and take away the animation block, the circle is drawn on the map and well north of where it should be. When I add the animation back, the circle just appears where it's supposed to (view.frame). Why would the animation not actually work even though I know the code is getting called?

Comment: I'm not sure. This code was taken from something I used to animate an annotation view, I've never tried it with an overlay. The animation block is iOS 4+, but I assume you're using that since it didn't crash. Check the frame before and after to see what's going on there.

Comment: don't animate using `frame`. A better choice is to animate via `transform`. For example from some offset +100x, +100y to the identity transform.

Comment: I'm not at my computer I'll try later